# Round a ruby float up or down to the nearest 0.05

Tags: ruby, floating-point, rounding

I'm getting numbers like

```
2.36363636363636
4.567563
1.234566465448465
10.5857447736
```

How would I get Ruby to round these numbers up (or down) to the nearest 0.05?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check this link out,  I think it's what you need.
[Ruby rounding](http://www.hans-eric.com/code-samples/ruby-floating-point-round-off/)

```
class Float
  def round_to(x)
    (self * 10**x).round.to_f / 10**x
  end

  def ceil_to(x)
    (self * 10**x).ceil.to_f / 10**x
  end

  def floor_to(x)
    (self * 10**x).floor.to_f / 10**x
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice link. Answer would be better with a summary, though, so it can stand on it's own, especially since the linked code doesn't do exactly what the OP asks, i.e., round to the nearest 0.05, but rounds to a particular decimal place.

Comment: And worse, b/c the post actually reimplements the built-in ruby function round(number-of-decimal-places), it's a bad idea.

Comment: downvote for only supplying a link, lame... and a link that doesn't even answer the question.

Comment: up vote since it does answer the question and round(x) isn't until ruby 0.9.6.

Comment: the monkey patching need not be necessary.   the technique by multiplying by factor, applying_a_function, then dividing by same factor is what you need. Next quarter-currency_unit? use 4 as the factor and `ciel.to_f`... and so on...

Comment: As other people have pointed out, this doesn't actually do what the question asks for...

Comment: The `ceil_to` function does not work consistently. For example, `0.07.ceil_to(2)` returns `0.08`, but SHOULD be `0.07`. The same occurs for 0.14, 0.28, 0.55, 1.09, etc.

Answer (score 25):

```
[2.36363636363636, 4.567563, 1.23456646544846, 10.5857447736].map do |x|
  (x*20).round / 20.0
end
#=> [2.35, 4.55, 1.25, 10.6]
```

Comment: Darn, you beat be me by a couple of seconds! +1 from me, although I had a slight different version in mind.

Comment: This doesn't round UP to the nearest 0.05 as requested by OP, 2.36.... should be 2.40, not 2.35.

Comment: @ChristopherMaujean True, but (despite the title) that's not what the OP asked for. The body of the question says "round these numbers up (**or down**) to the **nearest** 0.05". Anyway if you want to round up, use `ceil` instead of `round`.

Comment: I've edited the title to reflect the question, if I'm allowed, I'll remove my downvote.

Answer (score 20):

In general the algorithm for “rounding to the nearest *x*” is:

```
round(x / precision)) * precision
```

Sometimes is better to multiply by `1 / precision` because it is an integer (and thus it works a bit faster):

```
round(x * (1 / precision)) / (1 / precision)
```

In your case that would be:

```
round(x * (1 / 0.05)) / (1 / 0.05)
```

which would evaluate to:

```
round(x * 20) / 20;
```

I don’t know any Python, though, so the syntax might not be correct but I’m sure you can figure it out.

Comment: In order to get decimals divide by 20.0 -> round(x * 20) / 20.0;

Comment: For ruby: `(7.125 * 20).round / 20.0 => 7.15`

Answer (score 12):

To round to the nearest 2 places instead:

```
(5.65235534).round(2)
#=> 5.65
```

Comment: 5.6355.round(2) != 5.65, but TS wants 5.65

Comment: This solution only rounds the number to two decimal places, it does not return a rounded value to the nearest 0.05 as requested.

Comment: in some ways you're right, I should delete this answer. But on another level this is a very popular question that gets linked to in searches where people find this answer helpful, so I'm going to keep it visible

Answer (score 8):

Here's a general function that rounds by any given step value:

place in lib:

```
lib/rounding.rb
class Numeric
  # round a given number to the nearest step
  def round_by(increment)
    (self / increment).round * increment
  end
end
```

and the spec:

```
require 'rounding'
describe 'nearest increment by 0.5' do
  {0=>0.0,0.5=>0.5,0.60=>0.5,0.75=>1.0, 1.0=>1.0, 1.25=>1.5, 1.5=>1.5}.each_pair do |val, rounded_val|
    it "#{val}.round_by(0.5) ==#{rounded_val}" do val.round_by(0.5).should == rounded_val end
  end
end
```

and usage:

```
require 'rounding'
2.36363636363636.round_by(0.05)
```

hth.

Answer (score 5):

Ruby 2 now has a round function:

```
# Ruby 2.3
(2.5).round
 3

# Ruby 2.4
(2.5).round
 2
```

There are also options in ruby `2.4` like: `:even`, `:up` and `:down`
e.g;

```
(4.5).round(half: :up)
 5
```

Answer (score 4):

It’s possible to round numbers with `String` class’s `%` method.

For example

```
"%.2f" % 5.555555555
```

would give `"5.56"` as result (a string).

Answer (score 3):

To get a rounding result without decimals, use [Float's .round](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Float.html#method-i-round)

```
5.44.round
=> 5

5.54.round
=> 6
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question is old, but I like to share my invention with the world to help others: this is a method for **rounding float number with step, rounding decimal to closest given number**; it's usefull for rounding product price for example:

```
def round_with_step(value, rounding)
  decimals = rounding.to_i
  rounded_value = value.round(decimals)

  step_number = (rounding - rounding.to_i) * 10
  if step_number != 0
    step = step_number * 10**(0-decimals)
    rounded_value = ((value / step).round * step)
  end

  return (decimals > 0 ? "%.2f" : "%g") % rounded_value
end

# For example, the value is 234.567
#
# | ROUNDING | RETURN | STEP
# | 1        | 234.60 | 0.1
# | -1       | 230    | 10
# | 1.5      | 234.50 | 5 * 0.1 = 0.5
# | -1.5     | 250    | 5 * 10  = 50
# | 1.3      | 234.60 | 3 * 0.1 = 0.3
# | -1.3     | 240    | 3 * 10  = 30
```