# I have a numeric value like 30.6355 that represents money, how to round to 2 decimal places?

Tags: ruby, decimal, rounding

I have a numeric value like 30.6355 that represents money, how to round to 2 decimal places?

Comment: Are you selling gasoline? Why would you have money out to the 5th decimal point?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Round a ruby integer up to the nearest 0.05](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346257/round-a-ruby-integer-up-to-the-nearest-0-05) - question says 0.05 but the same technique applies to any unit, such as 0.01

Comment: Oh, money in float... again... Is `.0055` an accumulated float error? )))

Comment: @Jason Because many people that deal with money (need to) keep values much more precise than the average consumer...?

Comment: After computing tax or discounts, `>2` decimals are quite common...

Answer (score 20):

You **should not use `double` or `float` types when dealing with currency**: they have both too many decimal places and occasional rounding errors. Money can fall through those holes and it'll be tough to track down the errors after it happens.

When dealing with money, use a fixed decimal type. In Ruby (and Java), use BigDecimal.

Comment: Actually, the biggest problem is that they don't have any decimal places *at all*, they have *binary* places.

Comment: @Jörg, is right. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems for an explanation.

Comment: but Ruby doesn't have types? how can I make it bigdecimal??

Answer (score 13):

Ruby 1.8:

```
class Numeric
    def round_to( places )
        power = 10.0**places
        (self * power).round / power
    end
end

(30.6355).round_to(2)
```

Ruby 1.9:

```
(30.6355).round(2)
```

In 1.9, [round](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Float.html#method-i-round) can round to a specified number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

This will round for some useful cases - not well written but it works! Feel free to edit.

```
def round(numberString)
numberString = numberString.to_s
decimalLocation = numberString.index(".")
numbersAfterDecimal = numberString.slice(decimalLocation+1,numberString.length-1)
numbersBeforeAndIncludingDeciaml = numberString.slice(0,decimalLocation+1)

if numbersAfterDecimal.length <= 2
    return numberString.to_f
end

thingArray = numberString.split("")
thingArray.pop

prior = numbersAfterDecimal[-1].to_i
idx = numbersAfterDecimal.length-2

thingArray.reverse_each do |numStr|
    if prior >= 5
        numbersAfterDecimal[idx] = (numStr.to_i + 1).to_s unless (idx == 1 && numStr.to_i == 9)
        prior = (numStr.to_i + 1)
    else
        prior = numStr.to_i
    end
    break if (idx == 1)
    idx -= 1
end

resp = numbersBeforeAndIncludingDeciaml + numbersAfterDecimal[0..1]
resp.to_f
end
```

`round(18.00) == 18.0`

`round(18.99) == 18.99`

`round(17.9555555555) == 17.96`

`round(17.944444444445) == 17.95`

`round(15.545) == 15.55`

`round(15.55) == 15.55`

`round(15.555) == 15.56`

`round(1.18) == 1.18`

`round(1.189) == 1.19`