# What's the best way to round a Ruby BigDecimal number to the nearest 0.05?

Tags: ruby, bigdecimal, rounding

Ruby's BigDecimal #round method rounds numbers off to the nearest integer (and returns it as a fixnum frustratingly). Is there a built in method to allow rounding to the nearest 0.05? I can't find one.

The best I have managed is

```
def round05(number)
  (BigDecimal.new (number * 20).round.to_s) /20
end
```

Comment: Why `to_s`? _Oo And I think, you already managed the best way.

Comment: Be careful, what do you need to happen if `number` is less than zero? Should the rounding go towards zero or away from zero? Also, do you care if the rounding is biased? You might want to spend some time reading up on IEEE-754 and related standards before using a naive approach. Floating point is full of traps for the unwary.

Comment: @Nakilon
I needed to_s as BigDecimal.new won't accept a fixnum. Personally I think the BigDecimal library needs a bit of love.

Comment: @mu
The round method can be manipulated with the mode variable (e.g. round(1,ROUND_DOWN)) to get the desired behaviour.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Round a ruby integer up to the nearest 0.05](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346257/round-a-ruby-integer-up-to-the-nearest-0-05)

Comment: @my: I suspect the 0.05 is currency related, in which case you *don't* want it rounded from 0.01 to 0.00.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm in which case ROUND_UP should be used